# 2011 Jetta 2.5L Timing Chain VCDS Phase Position reads 0.00?

Tags: vw, jetta, timing, timing-chain

I recently bought a 2011 mk6 2.5L Jetta
with 150k miles on it cheap.

I don't know anything about this car's history and was curious about the status of the timing chain.

My RossTech cable seems to working fine for everything else on VCDS, but the Phase position under engine group 093 is reading 0.00 flat.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I don't know much about the VW engines, is this taking a reading while running or not?

Comment: Indeed, the reading was taken while the engine was running, after it had been idling for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would be reading "0.00 flat", but I don't think this should be considered an issue. If there is a fault in the VVT, the dash CEL will illuminate. Since the computer needs to know where the cam is at in the phase, it measures the cam angle. There are two parameters which should be looked at, which you should be able to find within VCDS:

- Cam adjustment specified
- Cam adjustment actual

If these are lock step (the same), there's no issue with your cam phasing. If they are different, there's an issue. An issue there can be for many different reasons, such as the wrong oil, carbon buildup, clogged oil passages within the phasing system, stuck lock pin, etc.

To maybe help you, [here is a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/juJ02ZCX9rw) I found which explains how the VW VVT system works.

Comment: Thanks, good advice, and that video overall was very informative. I went back and cleared all the fault codes(Most of which were from before I owned the vehicle) and took the reading again, and low and behold, I finally got a phase position reading (1.92). Not sure why I wasn't initially getting a reading but good to know in my case it wasn't a big deal.

Comment: It could be one or multiple codes were not allowing the VVT to function and thus held it at the 0.00 position as sort of a "safe" mode.